# How to generate this vector?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution

I have two vectors $A$, $B$ each containing 10 random numbers from standard normal distributions. I want to generate another vector $C$ of $10$ numbers from standard distribution where $\mathbb{E}[A\cdot B] = \mathbb{E}[B\cdot C] = 0$ (orthogonal), where $\mathbb{E}$ is the Expectation.

Apologize me, if I used incorrect notation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generate the vector independently from the other two, the expectation of $B\cdot C$ will vanish by symmetry, since a vector and its additive inverse are equiprobable. You can't influence $A\cdot B$ by how you generate $C$; whether its expectation value vanishes is determined by the joint distribution of $A$ and $B$, so this part of the question makes no sense.